Notation for work integrals in non-stationary force fields
I'm writing about work integrals and would usually use an expression like the following:
$$W = \int_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s} = \int_0^T \vec{F}(p(t)) \cdot \vec{v}(t) dt$$
where $W$ is work, $\vec{F}$ is the force, $p: [0, T] \rightarrow C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is the parametrisation of the curve in the line integral, $\vec{v} = \dot{\vec{p}}$ is the velocity of the object and $d\vec{s}$ is an infinitessimal unit of distance in the direction of $\vec{v}$.
This is all fine when $\vec{F}$ is a stationary force vector field which only depends on the spatial coordinates, but how should this be notated when $\vec{F}$ depends on time as well? I don't feel the right-hand-side is an issue, as this could just be $\vec{F}(p(t), t)$, but the left is more confusing. Would time and space be considered together, so $C$ is a parametrised curve through $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, where $n$ is the spatial dimension? And then the parametrisation for this extra dimenion is just $p(t) = (\text{... other dimensions} ..., t)$? This doesn't feel like a natural thing to do...

On the left-hand side, the time depency is actually implicit. Indeed, the path $C = \{s = x(t) \in \Bbb{R}^3 \;|\; t \in [0,T]\}$ cooresponds to the set of points "visited" by the physical object which is subjected to the force $F$; this path can be ultimately parametrized with the help of time $-$ because the latter is nothing else than a curvilinear coordinate used by the observer in order to measure the completion of a physical phenomenon (i.e. spatial motion in the present case) in the end.
In consequence, time and space are thus related by the time-parametrized trajectory $x(t)$. The concrete link between them is tranlated mathematically by Newton's third law, i.e. $m\ddot{x} = \sum_k F_k$, from which one can deduce the function $x = \phi(t)$ and invert it in order to find $t = \phi^{-1}(x)$.
Now, considering a force field $F(x,t)$, which is implicitly and explicity time-dependent through $x$ and $t$ respectively, the associated work is defined as
$$
W = \int_C F(x,t) \cdot \mathrm{d}x
$$
If you want to carry this computation as such, that is integrate it with respect to position, you will have to use parametrization coming from Newton's law, hence
$$
W = \int_C F\left(x,\phi^{-1}(x)\right) \cdot \mathrm{d}x
$$
On the other hand, if you want to do the same integration with respect to time, you will have to make the change of variable $x = \phi(t)$ in order to recover your right-hand side formula, i.e.
$$
W = \int_0^T F\left(\phi(t),t\right) \cdot \dot{\phi}(t) \,\mathrm{d}t
$$

Addendum. Finally, it is to be noted that other changes of variables are possible too. Indeed, in the case where $F$ is the only force in the system, hence $m\ddot{x} = F$ by Newton's law, then the integration can be done with respect to the velocity of the physical body, as done below :
$$
W = \int_C m\ddot{x} \cdot \mathrm{d}x = \int_{v(0)}^{v(T)} m\dot{x} \cdot \mathrm{d}\dot{x} = \left.\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}\right|_{v(0)}^{v(T)} = E_{kin}(T) - E_{kin}(0)
$$
One obtains a famous theorem stating that the work is given by the difference of final and initial kinetic energies. Moreover, if the considered force is conservative, meaning that it is derived from a potential $V(x)$, i.e. $F = -\nabla V$, then a similar result is valid as to potential energy, as it follows :
$$
W = -\int_C \nabla V(x) \cdot \mathrm{d}x = -\left(E_{pot}(T) - E_{pot}(0)\right)
$$
Unsurprisingly, assuming an adiabatic process without any heat loss, the variation of potential energy is compensated by the variation of the kinetic energy due to conservation of mechanical energy.

Hi @Abezhiko, thank you for your answer. I'm not sure about the assertion that the integration is purely spatial. What if the path is from $x=0$ to $x=1$, with force vector field $F=-t\vec{i}$ (i.e. an opposing force which increases with time). Then surely traversing this path really quickly, before the force grows, will require much less energy than traversing slowly, even though the path is the same?

@CountDirac-ula  I must admit my answer was ambiguous and not very explanatory, that is why I've edited it. Have a look.

Thank you for your updated answer, that clarifies things. I suppose I'm thinking about it like a particle being blown around, following the wind, in a 4D vector field of space and time. I.e. I don't want to prescribe a trajectory through space parametrised by time, but I'd like all such trajectories to be possible within the notation. Does it make sense to think like this? And would your answer still cover it, or would it be closer to my original thought of adding time as an additional dimension?
